# Headless not working for windows

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless

I am trying to run headless Chrome and it running normally without headless it just runs Chrome as normal.  I have updated chrome recently so that's not the issue.

```
driver.maximize_window()
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)


driver.get('https://www.youtube.com.au')
```

Comment: Are you using `driver.maximize_window()` and `driver.get('https://www.youtube.com.au')` for a different, non-headless browser? Your `browser` instance is what you should be using for headless browsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes to your code block as follows :

1. You need to maximize the browser once the webdriver opens the browser instance.
2. As per best practices to maximize the Chrome Window use `Options()` Class.
3. To maximize the Chrome Window through `Options()` Class either use the `start-maximized` argument or use the `window-size` argument.
4. Here is the sample code block for your reference:

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

   options = Options()
   options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
   options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
   options.add_argument("--headless");
   options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600");
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get("http://google.com/")
   print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
   ```